# Is HTTP method POST necessarily idempotent?

Tags: rest, http, post, idempotent

*I'm stuck in a theoretical issue with REST.*

Imagine a simple product stock API. The database contains one collection of movements referencing a `product`, a `quantity` and a `status`.

I have one prerequisite: I don't want the API users to manipulate the status. The status value can be `reserved` or `confirmed`.

First, I want to create a reservation of a product. Here is the corresponding URL path and HTTP method to represent that:

`[POST] /products/{product-id}/reservations`

This create the movement with a status `reserved` and return the id of the created movement.

Now, I want to confirm this reservation:

`[POST] /reservations/{movement-id}/confirmations`

In a semantic way, it seems to me that I create a confirmed reservation. In fact, I just change the status of the movement.

**So, 2 questions:**

1. My second POST is idempotent. I was unable to find the information in the RFC, but can a POST be idempotent?
2. Do you see a better way to represent the confirmation?

Comment: Personally, I don't see idempotent POST implementations often, because this method should not be used like that. An idempotent HTTP method is a HTTP method that can be called many times without different outcomes. If you want to stick to POST requests, just make sure that calling it multiple times does not change the outcome, or just use different method, such as PUT to change statuses, as it's used for modifications quite often.

Comment: You said "should not". In RFC terms, it's a meaningful word. Can you give me a resource confirming that? Alternatively, I don't think idempotency is about outcomes but more about the server status (a new entity has been created in the database, ...).

Comment: When talking about the `POST` request, the specification says that it's not idempotent. What this means is that idempotency is not guaranteed. However, it does not mean that you are _required_ to ensure that multiple `POST` requests do not yield the same outcome as issuing just one. So `POST` _may_ be idempotent, but unlike `PUT`, the specification does not guarantee it. `PUT` is indeed a more appropriate choice here though.

Answer (score 1):

I would use PUT instead. e.g. `PUT /reservations/{movement-id}/status "confirmed"`.

note:

It does not matter that your POST is idempotent, since you remove the link after the reservation was confirmed (HATEOAS), so the chance is very low that 2 confirmation arrive for the same reservation. Anyways I think PUT is a better fit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of course, I thought to your solution but as I said in my question, I do not want the user of the API to define new statuses. In your solution the status can be anything the user want. Moreover I'd prefer a more semantic use of the API. I didn't say that I use some hypermedia system but the question was more about: can POST request be idempotent or not?

Comment: @Gnucki You should validate the status. POST is usually not idempotent, but you can use it an idempotent way if you want. At least I did not find any restriction about this in the HTTP standard, only that you have to use 200 or 204 instead of 201 if there is no new resource. I don't suggest you to use POST that way, it is an exception for the case you did not find a better HTTP method, and not a rule.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your advice and search!